# Settings.BASE_DIR in django returning Windows path instead of Base directory

Tags: python, django

I ran these commands in the python shell

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.BASE_DIR)
```

This returned the project's absolute path as expected

"C:/Users/User/Desktop/Project"

But this was not the case when I tried accessing the same function in a function inside my custom filter, in which it started to return the windows path "C:/" instead.

filter.py

```
import os
from django import template
import moviepy.editor
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='vduration')
def vduration(videourl):
    video = video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, videourl))
    video_time = int(video.duration)
    video_time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=video_time))
    return video_time
```

in my settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os 

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Does anyone know what could be going on?